# Function that outputs second theme url

Tags: functions, multisite, themes, directory

I have a multisite and need a function (added to functions.php) that will get the template url of the second theme (probably by name or other identifier)?

Example:
theme-1 (used by main site) contains function to get url of theme-2 (theme-2 is used by sub-sites)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two inbuilt functions to do this.

1. [switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)
2. [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

You can use both in the following way to make a function out of it which would give you the url to the theme. Put the below in the **`functions.php`** file

```
function wpse_get_theme_url( $blog_id = 1 ){
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

    $template_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    restore_current_blog(); // Switch back to the original blog

    return $template_url;
}
```

Now you can use the above function to fetch the url by using the function and passing the blog id/ sub site id.

```
$theme_url = wpse_get_theme_url( $blog_id );
// Replace the $blog_id with blog id of your sub sites.
```